# What are the typical use-cases of (defun (setf …)) defsetf and define-setf-expander

Tags: common-lisp, setf

When developing with Common Lisp, we have three possibilities to define new `setf`-forms:

- We can define a function whose name is a list of two symbols, the first one being `setf`, e.g. `(defun (setf some-observable) (…))`.
- We can use the short form of `defsetf`.
- We can use the long form of `defsetf`.
- We can use `define-setf-expander`.

I am not sure what is the right or intended use-case for each of these possibilities.

A response to this question could hint at the most generic solution and outline contexts where other solutions are superior.

Comment: Well a setf function can be a generic function. Expanders can be used for destructuring (e.g. `values`), and to avoid computing the same thing twice, e.g. if you `incf` something in a hashtable, you shouldn’t need to hash/lookup the key twice.

Comment: "When developing a package" -> setf forms are unrelated to packages.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Fair enough. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`define-setf-expander` is the most general of these.  All of `setf`'s functionality is encompassed by it.

Defining a setf function works fine for most accessors.  It is also valid to use a generic function, so polymorphism is insufficient to require using something else.  Controlling evaluation either for correctness or performance is the main reason to *not* use a setf function.

For correctness, many forms of destructuring are not possible to do with a setf function (e.g. `(setf (values ...) ...)`).  Similarly I've seen an example that makes functional data structures behave locally like a mutable one by changing `(setf (dict-get key some-dict) 2)` to assign a new dictionary to `some-dict`.

For performance, consider the silly case of `(incf (nth 10000 list))` which if the `nth` writer were implemented as a function would require traversing 10k list nodes twice, but in a setf expander can be done with a single traversal.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for! Thanks!